# How can i deploy gmail addon to marketplace?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons

We have taken gSuite subscrption and has our own domain now I have created a gmail addon from app script dashboard. Now i wanted to deploy it to marketplace so that it can be added by any gmail user.

Since the default project created from app script dashboard is **Default GCP project** i have converted it to **standard GCP project** through which only we can deploy to marketplace. Now my question **how to deploy the addon to marketplace.** When i go to google cloud platforms console page i can see my project details and many options like Marketplace,billing, api & services, support and many others. If i select deployment manager from that it is asking me to take free trail or buy subscription. After Taking gSuite domain subscription do i need to buy again for deploying apps? Can someone give me clarity on this process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to use the deployment manager for publishing a Gmail Add-on on Marketplace.

To publish your Add-on, please follow the steps specified [here](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/publishing-gmail-addons).